# VBA to add totals and formula to multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet with around 200 work sheets each containing a list of products sold to a   company.

I need to add

1. A total at the bottom of row D-G where the bottom can be a different value. I.E. E4
2. below the total a formula based on the total.  I.E. if E4 (being the bottom of the above row) is below $999 the display text "samples", if between 1000-3000 then multiply E4 by 2%, 3001-7500 x 5% etc.

I need to be able to add it to the entire workbook easily using vba. Since I must do this to numerous ss it would literally save me 15-20 hours a month.

Edit:

So I have something that seems to be the right path.

```
Sub Split_Worksheets()
Dim rRange As Range, rCell As Range
Dim wSheet As Worksheet
Dim wSheetStart As Worksheet
Dim strText As String

Set wSheetStart = ActiveSheet
wSheetStart.AutoFilterMode = False
'Set a range variable to the correct item column
Set rRange = Range("A1", Range("A65536").End(xlUp))

 'Delete any sheet called "UniqueList"
 'Turn off run time errors & delete alert
 On Error Resume Next
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Worksheets("UniqueList").Delete

 'Add a sheet called "UniqueList"
 Worksheets.Add().Name = "UniqueList"

    'Filter the Set range so only a unique list is created
     With Worksheets("UniqueList")
          rRange.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , _
          Worksheets("UniqueList").Range("A1"), True

          'Set a range variable to the unique list, less the heading.
          Set rRange = .Range("A3", .Range("A65536").End(x2Up))
     End With

     On Error Resume Next
     With wSheetStart
         For Each rCell In rRange
           strText = rCell
           .Range("A1").AutoFilter 1, strText
             Worksheets(strText).Delete
             'Add a sheet named as content of rCell
             Worksheets.Add().Name = strText
             'Copy the visible filtered range _
             (default of Copy Method) and leave hidden rows
             .UsedRange.Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
             ActiveSheet.Cells.Columns.AutoFit
         Next rCell
     End With

 With wSheetStart
     .AutoFilterMode = False
     .Activate
 End With

 On Error GoTo 0
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Dim colm As Long, StartRow As Long
Dim EndCell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
StartRow = 3
For Each ws In Worksheets
    Set EndCell = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "c").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1)
    If EndCell.Row > StartRow Then EndCell.Resize(, 4).Formula = "=SUM(R" & StartRow & "C:R[-1]C)"
    Set EndCell = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)
    If EndCell.Row >= 1000 Then
    Range(J2) = Formula = ((EndCell.Row) * (0.05))
    Range(J3) = "5% Discount"
    ElseIf EndCell.Row >= 3000 Then
    Range(J2) = Formula = ((EndCell.Row) * (0.1))
    Range(J3) = "10% Discount"
    End If
Next ws
End Sub'
```

Just need to figure out how to display the results and text to the right cells (J2 in this case)

Comment: What have you tried thus far? You make it sound like you're in need of an employee, rather than a helping hand.

Comment: If been able to successfully use SUM then a LOOKUP formula (=E4*LOOKUP(E4,{0,999,3000,7500},{1,0.03,0.05,0.07}))  which has the right idea.  its not my preferred way to do it but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will supply the logic and all the references you need to put this one together; and will let you try to put it together on your own :). Come back for more help if needed.

1. You need to loop through all the worksheets in your workbook ([Microsoft Tutorial](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/142126))
2. You need to find the last row for the given columns ([Online tutorial](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm))
3. You need to use an `IF` statement to choose which formula to use ([MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx))

---

**UPDATE**

What's wrong with your code is this line :

```
Range(J2) = Formula = ((EndCell.Row) * (0.1))
```

What you're telling the computer is :

1. Multiply `EndCell.Row` by 0.1 (which has the number of the row below and to the right of the last cell in column C)
2. Compare `Formula` with the result previously obtained
3. Store the result of that logical expression at the range stored in variable `J2`

First of all, what you want is to put the result of the equation, and want to change `J2` to "J2" so it gets the cell J2, instead of the what's contained in `J2` (which has nothing at that point)

Also, you seem to say that you're not getting the right cells, maybe it is caused by this :

```
Set EndCell = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "c").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1)
```

In that line, you're finding the last cell of column C, but then you select the cell below, and to the right of it.

There are so many things wrong with your code it's hard to say what's not working properly.

Comment: Exactly! See? It's not that hard. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Still having some difficulties with if statements showing results in different cells but im getting there.